# How to read corrupted .py file

Tags: python

My .py file is corrupted in case of BSOD. If I open it in PyCharm it looks like empty file. If I open it in IPython it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVhrM.png)

UPD. Hexdump(My OS is Windows, but I did it in Linux)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh2g4.png)

UPD2. Everything is OK, I have dowloaded my file from Google Drive. Strangely, but earlier it suggests only last week file. Thanks all again.

Comment: Did you try to read it with an hexadecimal editor (like `hexdump`)?

Comment: No, how can I do it?

Comment: This actually looks like the the file contains only NUL characters, probably the result of the filesystem check resurrecting the file's blocks from thin air to maintain consistency. I hate to break this to you, but without a backup the file is probably gone.

Comment: I think you don't have chance to read it without VCS. Try to read more about Git maybe

Comment: @purplepsycho: `hexdump` has to be downloaded for Windows, I assume Windows because Linux/UNIX does not BSOD.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a quick n' dirty hex dump utility in python, since you are on Windows:

```
with open('gash.py', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        line_list = []
        for char in line:
            line_list.append("%02X" % (char))
        print(' '.join(line_list))
```

Where `gash.py` is the name of your python script.

That at least will tell you if there is anything that can be retrieved (but I doubt it).

Comment: It returns only zeros. Probably, nothing is there. Thank you and other.